# How to typecheck a destructured object with fallback values with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

How to typecheck a destructured object in the following structure?

```js
interface IUser  {
    username: string
    image: string
    uid: string
}

interface IDataProp {
    user: IUser
}

const {
    user: {
        username,
        image,
        uid
    } = {},
} = { ...data, user: data.user || {} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's a weird scenario and hard to cover.
I don't really understand why you would destructure the `data` object and the fulfill the `user` key with the `data.user` value.
The compilation error (or the type misleadding) lives in the default value. Since the assignment is not being applied to a strongly typed object, providing a default value which is an empty object `{}`, all variabled must have a default value (even an explicit `undefined`, depending on the `tsconfig.json`).

I guess there are two approaches.

```
const {
    user: {
        username,
        image,
        uid
    }
} = { user: data.user || {} };
```

No default `user`-key value. Now, all variables are `string` typed.
Second approach, admit the default `user` value but provide also explicit default values to variables

```
const {
    user: {
        username = undefined,
        image = 'default-image',
        uid = '000-000-0'
    } = {}
} = { user: data.user || {} };
```

It is a bit redundant and, in that case, `username` is of type union `string | undefined`... so it is quite a weak type.
In VSCode with a Typescript environment, if you hover up the `user` key, the compiler understands now that is an optional property `user?: IUser` of type `IUser`. This is why we must provide default values.

Finally, as I comment above, I found that scenario a bit weird. You could simply deconstruct the `data.user` object even with a void null-check providing a strongly typed deconstruction.

```
const {
    username,
    image,
    uid
}: IUser = { ...data.user || {} };
```